# How can we override from_basic method of doorkeeper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In doorkeeper gem of rails, access token get by the client by from_basic method of doorkeeper, i tried to customise this method, so that it is not easy for any outsider to get the access token.

I just add some more unique attribute with user name and email id, so that it become tough to get access token.

Here is the basic_method of doorkeeper:

```
def from_basic(request)
  authorization = request.authorization
  if authorization.present? && authorization =~ /^Basic (.*)/m
    Base64.decode64(Regexp.last_match(1)).split(/:/, 2)
  end
end
```

please provide me any suggestion how can i override this method

Comment: in which class or file have you added this function?
Is there a function by name `from_basic` in doorkeeper gem, if so in which file?

Comment: lib/doorkeeper/oauth/client/credentials.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is obviously security by obscurity, but it’s still easy with `Module#prepend`. Put this code anywhere in your initializers.

```rb
Doorkeeper::OAuth::Client.Credentials.
  singleton_class.prepend(Module.new do
    def from_basic(request)
      original = super(request)
      # my code that makes it better
    end
  end)
```